# Url of image component

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, component, image

I am not able to have url of the image component,though a part of tcm-id of component is showing as follows:

`<img src="@Model"/>` is rendering as `<img src="23746"/>`

`@Model.ToString()` is rendering as `Image: 23746`

But when I use `@Model.Url`, it returns null value.

Also, I have already published another component having that image component,and its success also.

What might be the issue?

**EDIT 1**:

"Image: 23746" is the tcm id of the image component which I am trying to map

**UPDATE 1**

After some tweaks, now the image url is coming, but an error of "image not found" is coming as follows:

```
Item '/en/media/myimage_tcm1010-23744.svg' not found for Localization '1010'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Seem to me you have not  Modelled  your Image Schema correctly. You need to use the DD4T `IMultimedia` and  the `[Multimedia]` Attribute

Comment: Model i m using is an existing one which has already been implemented..and..all the images related to it are coming dynamically..

Comment: If that is the case then you need to look at how it has been implemented to figure out how to get the image url  or  tell us how it has been implemented so we can help you. Just saying you are getting strings does not mean anything.

Comment: I am getting string of exact component for which i want the Url...does that also not mean anything?

Comment: This seems to be a DXA-based implementation? Do you see anything remarkable in the DXA log file (set log level to DEBUG if needed)? Did you configure your deployer to store binaries in the database?

Comment: Hi Bhawna, Can you please check if the URL works without the tcm id in it?
`/en/media/myimage.svg`

If it works, then the Component Template code is not proper at your end, and also can be a case where the image component is getting published with two dynamic CTs. Please confirm if this is happening.

Comment: Yup Sharad..it seems that Url without tcm id is working..and other one is not.might be because of DXA-based implementation,as suggested by Rick

Comment: Do you also have the same issue with images which are not SVG?

Comment: yes Rick,that issue was uniform,but just an update now, that issue is solved now.i will soon be posting an apt answer of what I think was causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for all of your support.This issue is finally resolved and here is a reference for anybody who will be facing this issue in the future.

The image component was using two Component Template(CT) during publishing(as seen in publish transaction of the successful "Processed Items" )

One was my CT and other was a dynamic one,and hence two image paths were created,one with tcmid (using my template) and other without tcmid (using dynamic one).

> Now the issue arises when my template was referencing the path without
>   tcmid returning a `404 not found error`, whereas the path without tcmid was available .

So , I changed the source of my template by replacing default setting("Default Dreamweaver Component Design")
with custom DXA("Render Component Content")

Also unpublished my page and then republished it.

Then only one image path with tcmid was created at time of publishing and that was referenced by my CT as well.

*Capisce*